# v-model on a newly created property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

On created I:

```
created: function () {

    _.forEach(this.users, (user) => {
        Vue.set(user, 'published', true);
    });
}
```

In my template I have:

```
<div v-for="user in this.users">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.published">
</div>
```

The issue is the checkbox does not seem to be bound to the newly set published property. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Please note, I am unable to change how I am adding the published property to each user.

Answer (score 0):

Try it that way:

```
<div v-for="user in users">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.published">
  <button @click="user.published=!user.published">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

In your hook:

```
created() {
    for (i in this.users) {
        this.users[i].published = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But by doing this you will lose the reactivity?

Comment: No, you can change each users.published to false and the checkbox will change.

Comment: I updated the code and inserted a button to demonstrate the reactivity.